# How to use Octokit in Swift3 ?

Tags: swift, cocoapods, octokit

I use Octkit for the first time and I used cocoapods to install it, but it does not work as it was explained in the GitHub: https://github.com/nerdishbynature/octokit.swift

So I tried to implement code this way;

```
let token = GithubAPIManager.sharedInstance.OAuthToken
    let config = TokenConfiguration(token)

    Octokit(config).me() { response in

        switch response {

        case .Success(let user):

        case .Failure(let error):

        }
    }
```

But when I add `TokenConfiguration` there is an error saying

> use of unresolved identifier

And also for the `Octkit(config)` there is an error. I imported Octokit and Foundation. What is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution is quite simple (had the same issue): in the example the reference to the enum is incorrect, additionally println isn't available in Swift 3 anymore.

.success and .failure need to be lowercase. If you want to print like the example in the readme file use print instead of println.

```
let token = GithubAPIManager.sharedInstance.OAuthToken
let config = TokenConfiguration(token)

Octokit(config).me() { response in

    switch response {

    case .success(let user):

    case .failure(let error):

    }
}
```